# PHP return the Two highest variables from four

Tags: php, arrays

Right now i am working on a simple PHP script.
I have four variables:

```
$test_a = 25;
$test_b = 24;
$test_c = 22;
$test_d = 35;
```

I want to display not the numbers from the variables. I need to extract only the two variables with the highest number.

So i need result something like this:

```
<?PHP echo "The two highest variables are: $test_a and $test_d";?>
```

So how i can extract only the two highest variables?

Comment: I would refer to http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php for how to use IFs in PHP to google for basic programming concepts.

Comment: I posted an answer but you should really show some additional effort.  What have you tried? What issues have you run into?

Answer (score 3):

Add the values to array, sort it in descending order, then take two first elements:

```
$a = array($test_a, $test_b, $test_c, $test_d);
arsort($a);
echo 'Two highest values:'.$a[0].' and '.$a[1];
```

Comment: I guess I overthought mine - this is cleaner!

Comment: Your example is giving the first two variables in the array but not the highest two...

Comment: The array is sorted in the second line, from high to low, so the first two elements are two highest.

Answer (score 1):

Put your values in an array: `$array = array(25, 24, 22, 35);` and get the first highest value using php [`max` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php):

```
$highest[] = max($array);  //store it in an array so you can compare using array_diff
```

Remove that value from your array w/ [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$array = array_diff($array, $highest);  //remove highest from original array
```

And then repeat finding highest with `max`:

```
$second_highest = max($array); 

 echo "The two highest variables are: $highest[0] and $second_highest";
```